# How to fill a 2-dimensional array in Java, adding the current row index to the previous row's integer items?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem with an (I guess) simple Java program. I need to create a two-dimensional array (that is called a "matrix", right?) which should look like this:

```
1 2 3 4  5  6  7  8  9 10   (1st row)
3 4 5 6  7  8  9 10 11 12   (2nd row)
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   (3rd row)
...
```

As you can see, the 1st row is `1, 2, 3, …`; the 2nd row is the 1st row with the 2nd row's row index added to each element. And so on: Every row is the previous row + the current row's row number (1-based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the number of columns and rows, and instantiate the array:

```
int columns = 10, rows = 3;
int[][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
```

Then do a loop for every row, and inside that loop, loop for every column, let's say you call the outer loop counter `i` and the inner loop counter `j`. Then you can assign a value in the array using this formula:

```
myArray[i][j] = j + ( (i+1) * (i+2) ) / 2;
```

This formula assumes `0 <= i < rows` and `0 <= j < columns`